# program program.exe has encountered wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

when I start splitcam.exe i get this error

The program program.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close.

Comment: Welcome to AU! We'll need a lot more detail to even begin to understand your issue. For instance, what is `splitcam.exe` and how did you install it? Which version of Wine do you use? Please reas [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the [scnow.zip](http://splitcam.biz/scnow.zip) from [splitcam.biz/download](http://splitcam.biz/download), extracted it, opened it with wine, which holds version number 1.7.44, install like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.7
```

and got it to open op:

[image]

As you can see, I am not really amused by the application. Therefore I must bring to your attention that there already are webcam applications,that run on (Linux)Ubuntu natively. [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) being my favorite. See here:

[image]

<sup>Image from [cheese/Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_%28software%29)</sup>

Doesn't that look better then some dodgy application you used from your Windows days???  **;-)**